# PIC18F25K80 4 > 20 returns true. How is this possible?

Tags: timer, pic, microchip, xc8

I'm using such code on PIC18F25K80 compiled with xc8 compiler:

```c
unsigned long kline_kw1281_byte_time = 0;

void sendKline(void) {
  klineWrite(0x9);
  while (klineBusy());
  kline_kw1281_byte_time = millis();
  while (!klineAvailable()) {
      if (kline_kw1281_byte_time_out()) {
          mStatus = DISCONNECTED;
          while(Busy1USART());
          Write1USART(0x00);
          return;
      }
  }
}


bit kline_kw1281_byte_time_out(void) {
    unsigned long time_out = millis() - kline_kw1281_byte_time;

    if (time_out > 20){
        while(Busy1USART());
        Write1USART(time_out);
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

and I have strange issue.  In `kline_kw1281_byte_time_out()` function I have true statement for `time_out > 20` but `Write1USART(time_out)` prints me lower number than 20. This happens random. The function most of the time works correctly.

this is millis() code:

```c
#include <p18cxxx.h>
#include "timer0.h"

volatile unsigned long runtime_millis;

void initialize_timer0() {
    T0CON = 0b11000011;
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;
    INTCON2bits.TMR0IP = 1; //set timer0 interrupt priority high
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0; //reset timer0 interrupt flag
}

void timer0(void) {
    runtime_millis++;
    TMR0L = 8;
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;
}

unsigned long millis(void) {
    return runtime_millis;
}

void delay(unsigned long ms) {
    unsigned long cTime = runtime_millis;
    while (runtime_millis - cTime < ms);
}
```

Comment: I can't see the problem you stated but I can see one in `delay()` which can fail when the `runtime_millis` counter wraps. A compiler can include code that tests the overflag and gives you the wrong answer. Better to use a stepping stone `do elapsed = runtime_millis - cTime; while (elapsed < ms);`. Also be careful when reading a value which is altered under interrupt, that is larger than a processor register, lest it changes between the multiple memory reads required. Better to disable the interrupt while you read the counter into another variable.

Comment: the value of time_out could be changing (perhaps by code in an interrupt thread or similar).  Try saving the value of time_out to another variable so that you're sure the value is the same at the time the 'if' test is evaluated as it as when you send the value to the UART.  Also if the value is 4 it could be an ASCII '4' which is 52 when it's an integer. '4' > 20 is true in the same way that 'A' > 20.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (time_out > 20){
    while(Busy1USART());
    Write1USART(time_out);
```

This writes `time_out` as ASCII character to the USART module. If you see '4' over the USART, that means the *ASCII character* '4', real value `0x34`, is sent. And `0x34`, 52 decimal, is greater than 20.

If you want to print the decimal value as a string to the USART, you can do this:

```
#define putch Write1USART 

printf("%ul", time_out);
```

The `printf()` function formats `time_out` as an unsigned long (hence `%ul`) and writes it byte by byte to `putch()`. `putch()` should therefore have the signature:

```
void putch(unsigned char);
```

The `#define` in the example above makes sure `Write1USART()` is used for `putch()`.